# How to prove that a revursive sequence is convergent or not, and if it is, how to find its limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Suppose $a_1 = 2$, and
>   $$ a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(a_n + \frac{2}{a_n}\right) $$
>   if $n \ge 1$.
>   Is the sequence convergent or divergent?
>   If it's convergent, find
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n}$$

Usually, what's the approach we use for recursive sequence like this?
A friend of mine told me that any recursive sequence is divergent, but after I checked on calculator, it seems that the series is approaching one particular value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, *Welcome to the site !*

If the limit exists, it is given by
$$L = \frac{1}{2}\left(L + \frac{2}{L}\right)\implies L=\pm \sqrt 2$$

Now, your turn !